# Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equation $y''+2y'+4(y')^3=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on the O.D.E. that $y''+2y'+4(y')^3=0$. (It's obvious that $y=C$ is a particular solution)

My solution is:

Let $p=y^{\prime}$, then $p^{\prime}+2p+4p^3=0$.

Let $\displaystyle u=\frac{1}{p^2}$, then I obtain $u'=4u+8$, hence $u=C\cdot e^{4x}-2$, so $\displaystyle y'=p=\sqrt{\frac{1}{C\cdot e^{4x}-2}}$.

But I don't know how to solve it next!

I also tried to deal with the equation $p^{\prime}+2p+4p^3=0$ by separating viariables but still can't obtain $y$.

Thank you for your direction!

Comment: $p^{\prime}+2p+4p^3=0$ It's Bernouilli's equation and what you did seems correct to me Zhang...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int \displaystyle dy= \int \frac{dx} {\sqrt{C e^{4x}-2}}$$
Try a substitution:
$$u=\sqrt{C e^{4x}-2}$$
$$u^2=C e^{4x}-2$$
$$2uu'=4Ce^{4x}$$
$$2udu=4(u^2+2)dx$$
$$ \implies dx= \dfrac {udu}{2(u^2+2)}$$

$$\int  dy= \int \frac{dx} {\sqrt{C e^{4x}-2}}$$
$$\int  dy= \int \dfrac {du}{2(u^2+2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $ y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{C\cdot e^{4x}-2}}$, then
$\int dy=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{C\cdot e^{4x}-2}}$.